# Why has Calibre stopped working?

Tags: calibre

Have used Calibre for years to transfer ebooks to my tablet but has stopped recognizing the device and any update for Calibre fail to work through Terminal.

Comment: Edit your answer with the following info: copy-paste the output when updating it does not work in the terminal. Also could be useful to name your Ubuntu flavor and version.

Comment: What is your tablet model and what operating system is running on your tablet?

Comment: if you are still using the python2 version of Calibre (Ubuntu 20.04?)... that one has died. Oh and we need errors messages to be able to help :)

Comment: OK, so it seems my Lenovo tablet is out of date, thanks for the help.